# Какую технологию  можно использовать,чтобы передавать потоковое видео в java?

Tags: java

Планируется просто чат с видео. Слышал про аналоги в Си, знает ли кто-нибудь о подобном в java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, в `BigBlueButton` (платформа для вебинаров) работа с потоковым видео с вебкамер реализована через [Red5](http://www.red5.org/) - медиасервер на Java. Лицензия Apache License 2.0.

Comment: Тоже как-то приходилось конференцию использовать. Заюзал wowza media server, намного понятнее в настройке + транскодер есть. Но удовольствие не дешёвое.